# Wait until end of thread execution before executing the next method

Tags: java, multithreading

I've a JFrame subclass that manage my UI and call a method of Item Object to import items in my DB:

```
public TestGUI() throws IOException
{

    initComponents();

    Item.importItems(progressBar); // static method that execute a new thread to import item witouth freeze my UI (I update a progressBar in it)

    table.refresh(); //Metodh that I need to execute only after "importItems()" methods is completed

}
```

The Item object implements Runnable to execute the import operation in a new Thread

```
public Item implements Runnable
{

    private JProgressBar progressBar;

    public void importItems (JProgressBar progressBar) throws IOException //Metodo per importare articoli da un file esterno. Usa i Thread.
    {

        this.progressBar = progressBar;

        Thread importThread = new Thread (new RefreshTable(),"Importer Thread");

        importThread.start();

    }

    void run ()
    {

        // I execute here all the DB operation that i need. I also update the progress bar             here

    }


}
```

How can I modify that code to execute the `table.refresh()` only after the `Item.importImtes(progressBar)` end its execution? thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want one Thread to wait for another, you can always use a **CountDownLatch** also. Using one also means that you do not have to wait until some threads finishes completely. If you *would* make your question better understandable for us, we could help with more details.

You need to share a CountDownLatch for example between the Threads:

```
public TestGUI() throws IOException{
      initComponents();
      private final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
      Item.importItems(progressBar, latch); // static method that execute a new thread to import item witouth freeze my UI (I update a progressBar in it)
      latch.await();
      table.refresh(); //Metodh that I need to execute only after "importItems()" methods is completed
}
```

And on the other side:

```
public Item implements Runnable {
    private JProgressBar progressBar;
    public void importItems (JProgressBar progressBar, CountDownLatch latch) throws IOException { //Metodo per importare articoli da un file esterno. Usa i Thread.

        this.progressBar = progressBar;

        Thread importThread = new Thread (new RefreshTable(),"Importer Thread");

        importThread.start();

    }

    void run () {

        // I execute here all the DB operation that i need. I also update the progress bar here
        //After everything finishes:
        latch.countDown(); // you want this to be executed in a finally block of the try catch
    }


}
```

Comment: I try to explain it better. check the first post in a few minutes. thanks!

Comment: With this code the <code>refries()</code> is correctly executed after import terminated but the big problem is that this freeze the UI and I can' t update the progressBar state. Any suggestion? thanks again!!

Comment: @Luca then you need to do table.refresh() in a new Thread., allowing the main Thread to execute further.

Comment: I had thought of this solution but I need to pass to the new thread the Table and that' s what i try to avoid. thanks

Comment: @Luca why are you trying to avoid it?

Comment: Because I try to create a class to works "magically". I'd rather complicated operations remain within the Item class.

Comment: @Luca: I see you have accepted an answer. How did you solve the problem in the end?

Comment: @Eugene: Wasn't he doing this already in the original question?

Answer (score 3):

use the .join() method on the thread.

Comment: The problem is that I can' t block the current Thread because in that current Thread I update the UI during the other Thread execution

Answer (score 2):

Check out [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) and [SwingUtilities](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html) in case you use `Swing`.
They contain helper threading APIs

Answer (score 0):

<Thread>.join() method would block the current thread until <Thread> is complete.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you should use it:

```
class ProgressBar extends Thread{
    public void run(){
        System.out.println("Progress Bar - start");
        try {
            Thread.currentThread().sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        System.out.println("Progress Bar - end");
    }
}
public class ThreadDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("Main Thread Start");
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new ProgressBar());
        t1.start();
        t1.join();
        System.out.println("Main Thread End");
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
Main Thread Start
Progress Bar - start
Progress Bar - end
Main Thread End
```

Comment: The problem in this code is that I can' t lock the current Thread with the .join() method because in that case I can' t update the UI in my app. I probably need a third Thread? Thanks!

Comment: @Luca seems like you will need 3 Threads 1) that executes the TestGUI method 2) one that does import items 3) another thread that will execute table.refresh(). You want 3 to wait for 2, but 1 will continue it's normal work?

Comment: @Luca Basically you want to start Thread 1 and thread 2 at the same time. Then Thread 1 should only terminate when Thread 2 has also terminated. Right ? If yes then... run thread 1 start, Thread 2 start, make thread 2 acquire a lock on and make thread 1 wait on it. When thread 2 finishes its work release the lock and finish processing for both the threads. how to work with Semaphores see my post on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12052232/thread-syncronization/12052750#12052750

Comment: I think that both Eugene and Vivek solution may works to solve my problem. I only need to choose the best way to do that. At first look I think that the Eugene solution could be more easiest to implement

Comment: @Luca actually I did not propose yet any solutions :)

Comment: @Eugene :D Yes but I understand which is your idea. unfortunately I can not implement it!

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is move the `table.refresh();` code at the end of the child thread code and use `SwingUtilities.InvokeLater` to forward it to the GUI thread event queue:

```
 public void run() {
      //...
      SwingUtilities.InvokeLater(
            new Runnable() {
                 public void run() {
                     table.refresh();
                 }
            });         
 }
```

That way you are executing it on the GUI thread but only when the child thread finished its work.